# Rails 3 link_to inside a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Everytime I am trying to combine a string with a link_to it is outputting in my browser as escaped HTML.

eg.

```
%(TEST #{link_to(object.title, object)})

OUTPUTS

TEST <a href="/objects/3">TEST OBJECT</a>
```

Why is this happening ?  Every example I see on net the link_to does not get escaped.

Comment: Could you please post the output you had hoped to achieve instead?

Comment: @Phrogz he expects a link, but he literally sees the html in his browser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Output is escaped by default in Rails 3. If you append `.html_safe` to your string it will do what you expect.

```
%(TEST #{link_to(object.title, object)}).html_safe
```

Comment: I do not think that this is principially good idea - it is neglecting the very reason of this change in rails 3. You should first samitize the object.title if it is provided by user and than you can do this.

Answer (score 4):

This also do the job:

```
<%=raw %(TEST #{link_to(object.title, object)}) %>
```