# How to put link_to inside string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here i have found similar question [Rails 3 link_to inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506229/rails-3-link-to-inside-a-string?answertab=active#tab-top) but somehow its not working for my scenario.

I have a `@matter` object which has url like below.

```
@matter = url_for(:controller => 'news', :action => 'news_view',:id => @news.token)
```

I am trying to put this link inside text , which can be done by simply putting "#{@matter}". But i want to put a alias of that whole link generated like 'VIEW NEWS' and when user clicks on it, it will redirect to original url.

Using this i have to send to my link to both mail and mobile text. I got it for email but not able to do it for sending text, as `:body` requires string format for message API.

I have followed above mentioned SO post, but they are not at all working for me.

`"\"#{@news.sender.first_name} #{@news.sender.last_name} just sent you a invite.\" Click on link raw('<%= link_to 'View Invite', @method) %>') ")`

I am ok with using html inside string like `<a href ="#{@matter}", view invite </a>` if possible.

Help required.

I am using twilio to send text using below API.

```
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @account_sid, @auth_token
  @client.account.messages.create(:from => '+123456789', :to => '+1'+@phone, 
                                  :body => "#{@matter}" )
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do as the following:

```
"#{@news.sender.first_name} #{@news.sender.first_name} just sent you an invite."
"Click on link to #{link_to 'View invite', @matter}".html_safe
```

If used in your controller, you can access to your `view_context`:

```
def show
  # ...
  @message  = "#{@news.sender.first_name} #{@news.sender.first_name} just sent you an invite."
  @message << "Click on link to #{view_context.link_to 'View invite', @matter}"

  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @account_sid, @auth_token
  @client.account.messages.create(:from => '+123456789', :to => '+1'+@phone, 
                              :body => @message.html_safe )
end
```

Comment: its saying `undefined method `link_to' for #<NewsController:0x007f4c4053b3d8>`

Comment: my question is ..as this is sent as text to mobile, is above metioned error anyway related to that ?

Comment: when i used the new way, i am receiving text as `first_name second_nam just sent you a invite. Click on link to <a href="http://www.example.com/abc>View Invite</a>`

Comment: @Rahul I don't know if text messages can handle HTML. I think that my iPhone can do it, but how? You will have to do some research on your side to determine how to include a HTTP link inside a text message.

Comment: sure.. as of now my message is still showing as above mentioned. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will have to set the domain to the link_to: as you send the link to an external "plateform", you need to prepend your links `/news/news_view/<id>` with the domain of your app, something like `http://example.com/news/news_view/<id>`

Comment: ya i did using `@matter = url_for(:controller => 'news', :action => 'news_view',:id => @news.token, host: 'www.example.com')`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like we cannot include hyperlink in text message due to privacy issues. This post says so 
[create hyperlink in sms in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582223/create-hyperlink-in-sms-in-iphone). That is why though i tried MrYoshiji's answers, i was not getting text properly as i wanted.

Comment: I think at this point the best practice is to just insert the link as text and let the phone client display as it will. For example, on the iPhone inserting `http://testing.com` will be clickable in the Messages app and open the link in Safari.