# Rails 4: Embed link in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, link-to

I have a string field in one of my controllers which is a message. I want to embed a clickable link in it.

Something like this works in the view:

```
<% dd = "Click on link to #{link_to 'View ', "www.google.com"} asdad"  %>
<%= dd.html_safe %>
```

but in the controller its not possible to store `dd` and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `link_to' for ...
```

I tried also `to_s` :

```
<% dd = "Click on link to #{link_to 'View ', "www.google.com"} asdad".to_s %>  
Message.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :cnt => dd)
```

but still the same error. Please, help me to know how can I embed a link into string in rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

## in the controller code

```
view_context.link_to '...', '...'
```

Comment: Thank you, I've found it some minutes ago, more information for people who will visit this page later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813895/how-to-put-link-to-inside-string-in-rails